# Vector layer does not appear with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, vector

When I import the vector it simply does not show in the map. I tried with a raster and it worked fine. I tried now with both KML and GeoJSON and the same thing happen, I can see that it loaded in the Chrome Dev Tool and I can also see the data from there, but not in the map. I using the [Vector Layer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html) and the [Image Vector Layer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/image-vector-layer.html) as a base.

The projection is EPSG:31982, UTM 22 S - Sirgas 2000

I'm using OpenLayers v5.3

I tried some things that I found in examples online, but none seems to work. 
Other questions related that did not helped me:

- [Vector layer not displaying in OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254011/vector-layer-not-displaying-in-openlayers/254173)
- [OpenLayers does not display vector tiles in their origin projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271617/openlayers-does-not-display-vector-tiles-in-their-origin-projection)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688466/vector-layer-is-not-showing-in-openlayers-3
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49769770/openlayers-4-wont-display-vector-layer
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124081/openlayers-vector-layer-not-showing-on-the-whole-screen
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879232/features-added-to-vector-layer-are-not-visible
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491164/openlayers-vector-features-layer-invisible-do-not-render
- [OpenLayers 4 does not display vector layer from geoJSON](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230678/openlayers-4-does-not-display-vector-layer-from-geojson)
- [Layer does not displaying](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273932/layer-does-not-displaying)
- [Not displaying any layers in OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266032/not-displaying-any-layers-in-openlayers)
- [Openlayers 3 Circle Vectors Not Visible](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141429/openlayers-3-circle-vectors-not-visible)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49769770/openlayers-4-wont-display-vector-layer

Sample code I'm using:

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:31982', '+proj=utm +zone=22 +south +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs');
register(proj4);

var map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
    new VectorLayer({
      renderMode: 'image',
      source: new VectorSource({
        url: 'img/estradas.geojson',
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        projection: 'EPSG:31982'
      }),
      style: function(feature) {
        style.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
        return style;
      }
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: transform(getCenter(imageExtent), 'EPSG:31982', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 13
  })
});
```

Comment: Please set up a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: `projection` isn't a valid option for `VectorSource`.  If you geojson contains EPSG:31982 coordinates you should replace `format: new GeoJSON(), projection: 'EPSG:31982'` with `format: new GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:31982'})`

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much. I looked lots of examples and any of them presented this method. The only thing that become different is the vector color, but I think I can change this with the style attribute. If you want to write the answer I can mark as correct :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For vector layers the data projection should be specified in the format, not the source:

```
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: 'img/estradas.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:31982'})
  }),
```